# Hola tengo que realizar una función que sume dos números

Tags: python, google-colab

## Programa que suma dos numeros pero tengo un error soy nuevo en esto y no comprendo bien. Estoy usando Python en colab de google.

```
def sumador(num_1, num_2)
return (num1 + num2)
num_1 = int(input("El primer numero es "))
num_2 = int(input("El segundo numero es "))

print("La suma es " + str(sumador(num_1, num_2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Revisando tu función no está del todo mal, los errores que seguramente estás recibiendo son por sintaxis. Al incio no estás colocando los dos puntos en la función, debe ser: 'def sumador(num_1, num_2)***:***'. Por otro lado, en el return estás utilizando mal las variables, estás llamando a **num1** y **num2** pero tus variables se llaman **num_1** y **num_2**. De ahí en fuera todo parece estar bien, es importante recordar la indentación en la función.

```
def sumador(num_1, num_2):
    return (num_1 + num_2)
num_1 = int(input("El primer numero es "))
num_2 = int(input("El segundo numero es "))
print("La suma es " + str(sumador(num_1, num_2)))
```